# How to deploy a gradle project

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am working mostly in notepad. developed many projects in core java and servlets with Tomcat but don't know how to deploy a Gradle project. I am trying to configure https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api. Please assist me

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link fixed my problem http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example/

I have downloaded the gradle package set its path to bin folder and build the package by studying the aforementioned link as to how gradle works

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

1. Create war file for your project.
2. Stop the server(not mandatory)
3. Copy that .war file to your tomcat webapps folder.
4. Start the server(After starting one folder with your war file name
   will be created).
5. Open `localhost:8080/<war name>`

That's it

**Note:** This is common process for all not only for gradle, 8080 port may vary(By Default tomcat ll take 8080).

Comment: Directory Listing For /telegram/ it showing  files/folders instead of running the project

Comment: Are you getting tomcat home page on opening localhost:8080

Comment: yes my tomcat page is http://127.0.0.1:7070/. How this project can be ran whereas its not have any Deployment Descriptor or WEB-INF folder?